# Is it possible to add R Code inside an HTML tag in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is it possible to add R code chunks inside an HTML tag?

For example:

```
<div class="cards-list">
  <div class="stat-card">
    <div class="stat-icon right"><span class="bg-ontrack"></span></i></div>
    <h3>Impressions</h3>
    <h4 class="stat-num"><span class="txt-ontrack">{r code}</span></h4>
 </div>
</div>
```

I need to add an R Code chunk inside an HTML tag here let's say in  tag. That means the class should be applied to the output of the R code chunk.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi! It would be much better to give a reproducible example and expected output.

Comment: @NaremanDarwish did that!